# SSL: :certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1507:Fatal error: certificate expired

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying to update dependencies on a phoenix app by running: `mix deps.get`

The only STOUT is:

```
07:20:21.642 [error] SSL: :certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1507:Fatal error: certificate expired


07:20:21.674 [error] SSL: :certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1507:Fatal error: certificate expired

Registry update failed (http_error)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:tls_alert, 'certificate expired'}}]}
** (Mix) Failed to fetch registry
```

I have updated elixir and erlang with `brew update` but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since the certificate for repo.hex.pm is not expired in reality but is very recently issued the error message might be cause by a wrong time on your computer. Thus make sure that you have the current time on your system and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I assume executing `date` would check to make sure that it is correct? If so, it matches the time it is now.

Comment: @BillPiper123: and you get still the same error message?

Comment: Yes I did not change anything

Comment: @BillPiper123: it would be interesting to get the full output of `openssl s_client -connect repo.hex.pm:443 -servername repo.hex.pm`  from your system to further debug the issue

Comment: Part of it is `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`, I assume this is what the issue is?

Comment: @BillPiper123: probably not, the error message you have included in your question says *certificate expired*. But I'm probably unable to help further unless you also add the **full** output from the openssl command to your question instead of quoting only a single line

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm running into the same issue. Here's a full output of the command you've mentioned: https://gist.github.com/gmile/9adbf4e8db106175821b1dc6a308fcd8

Comment: @gmile: from the certificate: Not Before: Oct 30 10:27:09 2016 GMT, Not After : Dec 28 14:42:52 2018 GMT. Thus the certificate is valid but your clock might be off.